# Pivot Table Join Data Issue

Tags: mysql, inner-join, pivot-table

I have the following MYSQL table

```
   fieldName    fieldData   businessUnitId    clientId
    SJM ID       123456      1                 1
    Username     abcdedg     1                 1
    First Name   Danny       1                 1
    Last Name    Younes      1                 1
    Email        test@t.com  1                 1
    SJM ID       123456      4                 1
    Dealer Code  123456      4                 1
    Dealer       South Port  4                 1
```

I want to merge all the fields together with the different business units

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
MAX(IF(sso3.fieldName = 'SJM ID', sso3.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'SJMID', 
MAX(IF(sso3.fieldName = 'Username', sso3.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'USERNAME', 
MAX(IF(sso3.fieldName = 'First Name', sso3.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'FIRST NAME', 
MAX(IF(sso3.fieldName = 'Last Name', sso3.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'LAST NAME', 
MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Dealer Code', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'DCODE',
MAX(IF(sso3.fieldName = 'Email', sso3.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Email' 
FROM mi_ssousers2 sso2 inner join mi_ssousers2 sso3 on sso3.clientId=sso2.clientId 
WHERE sso2.businessUnitId=4 and sso3.businessUnitId=1 group by sso2.clientId
```

but it renders me the following result and I get random results from other records in the table

```
SJMID     USERNAME      FIRST NAME    LAST NAME    DCODE    Email
123456    RANDON VALUE  RANDOM VALUE  RANDOM VALUE 123456   RANDOM VALUE
```

The expected output is as follows

```
SJM ID     USERNAME    FIRST NAME     LAST NAME    DCODE     EMAIL
123456     abcdefg     Danny          Younes       123456    test@t.com
```

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Can you include you expected output ?

Comment: Hi Khalid I have updated the original questions, thank you

Comment: Remove `MAX`...